# What is the best way to thread work in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What's the best way to thread work (methods) in c#?

For example:

Let's say I have a form and want to load data from db.

```
My form controls: 
 - dataGridView (to show data from DB), 
 - label (loading status) and 
 - button (start loading).
```

When I click the button my form is frozen until the task is done. Also the loading status does not change until task is done. I think async threading would be the answer?

So my question: what's the best way to handle this? I know there is a lot stuff about Threading, but what's the difference between them and how do you make it thread safe?

How do you solve this kind of problems?

Best Regards.

Comment: What is the best way to thread work in c#? Carefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no universal 'best' way to thread work.  You just have to try different ways of doing things, I'm afraid.

I particularly like Jeremy D. Miller's continuation idea described [at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309512.aspx) (scroll down to find the "continuations" section).  It's really elegant and means writing very little boilerplate code.

Basically, when you call "ExecuteWithContinuation" with a Func argument, the function is executed asynchronously, then returns an action when it finishes.  The action is then marshalled back onto your UI thread to act as a continuation.  This allows you to quickly split your operations into two bits:

1. Perform long running operation that shouldn't block the UI
2. ... when finished, update the UI on the UI thread

It takes a bit of getting used to, but it's pretty cool.

```
public class AsyncCommandExecutor : ICommandExecutor
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext m_context;

    public AsyncCommandExecutor(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        m_context = context;
    }

    public void Execute(Action command)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => command());

    }

    public void ExecuteWithContinuation(Func<Action> command)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                                         {
                                             var continuation = command();
                                             m_context.Send(x => continuation(), null);
                                         });
    }
}
```

You'd then use it like this (forgive the formatting...)

```
public void DoSomethingThatTakesAgesAndNeedsToUpdateUiWhenFinished()
{
    DisableUi();
    m_commandExecutor.ExecuteWithContinuation(
                () =>
                    {
                        // this is the long-running bit
                        ConnectToServer();

                        // This is the continuation that will be run
                        // on the UI thread
                        return () =>
                                    {
                                        EnableUi();
                                    };
                    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I use it without lambda in .NET 2.0?

Comment: Mark now I'm on .NET 3.5. I got the error:Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires '1' type arguments. What to do?

Comment: "Action<T>" is the generic action that has one parameter; the code I posted just uses "Action" which has no parameters.  It looks like you're trying to use Action<T> instead of Action.  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Comment: Hey Mark. I tried your solution and it works great. Could you pleas show how to return some values from ExecuteWithContinuation section? Let's say I have DoSomethingThatTakesAgesAndNeedsToUpdateUiWhenFinished(int i) and want to change the variable. How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

If using Windows Forms, you should look at [BackrgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(VS.95).aspx). More generally, it is often useful to use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(VS.95).aspx) class. And finally, it is worth to take a look at the new .NET 4's [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(VS.100).aspx) class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I'm using win forms and .NET 2.0. I tried ThreadPool's from AdamRalph's answer and get and error: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Once you move the work onto another thread, it can no longer directly access the user interface (hence the cross-thread call). You need to use Control.Invoke() or Control.BeginInvoke() to pass control back to the UI thread to ask it to update the UI for you.

Comment: That's why the `BackgroundWorker` class is nice; it raises events on the UI thread so no `Invoke()` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of pattern:-

```
    private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = "Working...";
        RefreshButton.Enabled = false;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
        {
            // do work here 
            // e.g. 
            object datasource = GetData();
            this.Invoke((Action<object>)delegate(object obj)
            {
                // gridview should also be accessed in UI thread 
                // e.g. 
                MyGridView.DataSource = obj;

                MessageLabel.Text = "Done.";
                RefreshButton.Enabled = true;
            }, datasource);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where to call Control.Invoke()? I get an error:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: I've converted the code Winforms.  Note that you have to manipulate the gridview in the UI thread too, since it is a UI element. This will eliminate the runtime exception you are seeing.

Comment: I have changed my framework to 3.5. Now it works. Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your controls from the code that runs in the spun-off thread - the framework does not allow this, which explains the error you are getting.

You need to cache the data retrieved from the db in a non-forms object and populate your UI with data from that object after the background worker thread is done (and handle synchronization for access to that object).

Comment: Actually, the `CrossThreadException` will only be thrown in debug mode.